# Unity Android C# Отслеживания нажатия

Tags: android, c#, unity3d

Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на экран выполнялась функция, причем только один раз, пока не нажмешь снова (как в FlappyBird). У меня же при прикосновении к экрану он выполняется, пока не отпустишь палец. Использовал Input.touchCount>0

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Selectable.OnPointerDown.html

Answer (score 6):

Очевидно, что отслеживать лишь то, что имеет место нажатие - недостаточно. Надо еще отслеживать фазу.

**[TouchPhase](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/TouchPhase.html)** - список возможных фаз

```
Began   - Палец коснулся экрана.
Moved   - Палец передвинулся по экрану.
Stationary  - Палец коснулся экрана, но не сдвинулся.
Ended   - Палец только что оторван от экрана. Это последняя фаза нажатий.
Canceled    - Система отменила отслеживание касаний.
```

Пример там можно подглядеть: https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/Touch-phase.html

И в итоге написать что-то типа:

```
void Update() {        
    if (Input.touchCount > 0) {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
            // что-то делать
        }
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Первый вариант описан выше, использовать фазу Began.
Я в подобном проекте использовал условие if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)). Прекрасно работало и на android девайсах.

Answer (score 1):

Я не делал игры под Android и сенсооные экраны в принципе, но думаю, под Stationary нужно сделать мертвую зону, палец все-таки дрожит у всех.